# Stopping a thread in python, why does the following not work?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have been trying to provide the functionality to stop a thread following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) . I have the following class:

```
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self, id):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()
        self._id = id
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped():
            print ("Thread with id {0} Running".format(self._id))
            time.sleep(1)
```

When I create 10 threads and try to stop them, none of them stop and keep printing.

```
threads = [WorkerThread(x) for x in range(10)]
[thread.start() for thread in threads]
time.sleep(2) #wait
[thread.stop() for thread in threads]
[thread.join() for thread in threads]
print "All done" #never printed
```

Can someone explain why the stop event is ignored? I also tried using the `_stop` attribute as a flag and setting it to false in `__init__` and `True` in `stop()` with no luck.

Comment: `super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()`: Is StoppableThread a typo?

Comment: Works fine with Python 2.7.6 on Linux x86-64.

Comment: Works fine for me as well, apart from the "seld._id" typo.

Comment: @mlk I fixed that in the post but I think the original code doesn't have the typo.

Comment: @ismail yes it was a typo while editing. Somehow I cannot copy into SO directly.

Comment: The code as shown works for me on Python 2.7.7 (i.e. the threads stop).  And, according to my understanding of the `threading` library, it *should* work.

Comment: I just used this method today and it worked for me